# How do I solve `Lisp error: (void-function -compose)` when using gopls?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

I'm trying to use Golang with LSP in Emacs 27.2 (Fedora 35) but whenever I run `M-x lsp-mode` it shows as disconnected and when I try to run `M-x lsp` it shows the `Lisp error: (void-function -compose)`.

Everything was installed through MELPA and everything is up to the latest versions.

`gopls` is reachable through my `PATH`.

Be noted that updating the `dash` package and deleting every other instance of it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I note that you updated `dash.el`.  Following that, you should also try re-compiling `gopls.el`.  The easiest way to be sure of getting this right is to reinstall it.

The reason is that you may (should) be using the compiled version of `gopls.el`, which will be in a file called `gopls.elc`, and this will have been compiled against the earlier version of dash. Alternatively, you can just delete the `.elc` file and Emacs will correctly find the current `-compose` function at runtime, at the cost of a small performance hit.